# NSUrlConnection conection:didReceiveResponse not being called during HTTP 302 redirects

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming, nsurlconnection

I have a class that implements `NSURLProtocol` and initiates a new `NSURLConnection` in `startLoading` method. I also need the HTTP responses for all requests, so I do this by implementing data delegate method `connection:didReceiveResponse`. For HTTP redirects, I also implement `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` wherein I call the NSURLProtocolClient Method for redirects. Below is the code

```
(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
             redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (response) {
        [self.client URLProtocol:self 
          wasRedirectedToRequest:request 
                redirectResponse:response];
    }

    return request;
}
```

The problem with this code is `connection:didReceiveResponse` never gets called when redirectResponse is not `nil`. When I comment out the protocol client's `URLProtocol:wasRedirectedToRequest:redirectResponse` method, `connection:didReceiveResponse` starts getting called again.

I am not sure what's going on here. Can anybody shed some light on this behavior ?

Comment: What is the client doing in `wasRedirectedToRequest...`

Comment: The client is iOS's internal implementation for URL loading system. It needs to be called within you own implementations. http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial